# Does James Woods have an IQ of 180?

Tags: intelligence

An article [claimed](http://listverse.com/2009/01/18/15-surprisingly-super-smart-celebrities/) that the Actor James Woods has an IQ of 180:

> **Woods aced his SATs, got into MIT** (but dropped out to pursue acting) and has a reported IQ of 180.

After doing some research, I found a lot of articles which also **said that he has an IQ of 180**, but I couldn't find any reliable reference for their claim.

The only reference I could find, was that Woods stated his IQ-Number in some interviews.

So, my questions is, is this true or a not? Is there a proof of his IQ?

Comment: What sort of evidence would you expect that would satisfy you?

Comment: As i wrote before my post was edited, maybe a copy of a test,  maybe some information about if it only was one test. I dont know exactly what would satisfy me, i was just wondering that there are thousand article which mention it, but i could not find one article with more details, except the statement: "He has an IQ of 180". Even some information like: He made that type of IQ-Test at that age and that place would be interesting. I am just wondering, i could believe that he is intelligent, but 180 is unusual high, especially for an "Mainstream"-actor...

Comment: You are excluding the most likely evidence for this (e.g. his own statements). IQ tests are not normally public knowledge.

Comment: Ok, a statement where he says more about this then "my IQ is 180" would also be ok, as i said, i just want some more Information about this, a proof if exists, more Details if no proof exists. I dont want to exclude something here. All i have now is some unreferenced statements in articles...

Comment: It's worth noting that most standard IQ tests have an upper limit of 160, which represents a rarity of roughly 1 in 30,000 people (IQ being normalised so that 100 is average within a given population). An IQ of 171 would apparently represent 1 in a million, if any test were designed to measure that high (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega_Society)

Comment: Probably not. IQ tests are not reliable when they are that high; he probably never took an IQ test, etc

Comment: I'm sure that at one time in his life, perhaps when he was a child, Mr Woods was given a score of 180 in one IQ test. But there are different tests, people tested at different times score differently, age is a big factor ... to go around saying you "have" an IQ which is reducible to one number is probably an indication you don't know what IQ is all about.

Comment: @RaceBannon - Agreed. Once you get to a certain point, I think any actual professional would just put a "+" next to wherever that particular standard deviation ended, rather than try to quantify it to an exact number. This is one of the most common unverified claims around, I'd think. I remember reading in Rolling Stone how Axyl Rose was a proven-tested genius, along with anyone else who famous was basically a jerk. Not accusing Woods, by the way, don't know enough about him, though he does play that particular role very well.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**No: these news are not credible at all.**

The report was investigated by [Daily Edge](http://www.dailyedge.ie/celebrity-genius-mensa-944924-Jun2013/) and found to be unreliable for two reasons:

1. it was traced to a single source, [Sinembargo.mx](http://www.sinembargo.mx/01-06-2013/640797) and of course this makes the claim unverifiable by skeptical standards.

   > The source for all the stories appears to be this story from June 1 on Sinembargo, a Mexican online news site.
2. The news are claimed to come from Mensa, but they have categorically [disclaimed this](http://www.mensa.org/news/mensa-international-refutes-recent-press-stories).

   > Mensa International has NOT issued a list of celebrity members recently, as many on-line stories have been claiming. Attempts are being made by Mensa to discover the source of these stories and to have false claims removed.

Furthermore, the numbers are impossibly high!

- [A perfect Mensa test gives a score of 162](http://www.theguardian.com/society/2015/sep/02/girl-12-wins-maximum-mensa-iq-test-score), but a score of 180 is claimed, and the news are reported in national newspapers. The wikipedia article on Woods does not report anything, which seems highly unlikely.
- Even with a specialized test to measure such a high IQ, a score of 180 is extremely unlikely. Based on how IQ scores are built, [1 σ is 15 IQ points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_quotient), therefore a score of 180 represents a 5.33σ percentile. This means that is achieved only in [1 test in 20,000,000](http://www.six-sigma-material.com/Tables.html). Not impossible, but certainly an extraordinary claim without any evidence.

[image: sigma table]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79058/discussion-on-answer-by-sklivvz-does-james-woods-have-an-iq-of-180).

Comment: Something I was told when *I* took my Mensa test: IQ tests have a "target value", around which they give somewhat reliable results. Score too high or too low (we were told, around +-15 points of the target value), and all the result tells you is "you should take a different IQ test for *your* range". This, immediately, gives a significant difference between "average" IQ tests (aimed at around 100, losing meaning above 115) and Mensa entry tests (aimed at around 130, losing meaning above 145).