# Do these five football players have exceptionally high IQs?

Tags: psychology, intelligence, football

This [Sokkaa.com article](http://sokkaa.com/footballs-einsteins-five-footballers-with-the-highest-iq-score/) is one of many claiming that these handful of football players have exceptionally high IQs.

> Most of the football players in the world are evaluated based on physical health, speed, skills, etc. However, some famous footballers have the highest IQ score. Down are the footballers with the highest IQ score in the world.
>
> 5. Juan Mata -IQ score: 142
> [...] 
> 4. Frank Lampard -IQ score: 150
> [...] 
> 3. Mario Balotelli -IQ score: 157
> [...] 
> 2. Arsene Wenger -IQ score: 157
> [...] 
> 1. Gerard Pique -IQ score: 170
> [...]

I can't find any reliable reference for their claim. Is it true?

Comment: Oddthinking, is it OK to use "genius IQ" in the title? Is that subjective?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does James Woods have an IQ of 180?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28536/does-james-woods-have-an-iq-of-180)

Comment: According to https://www.verywellmind.com/what-is-a-genius-iq-score-2795585 genius level starts at 160 so that makes the list shorter.

Comment: According to Sklivvz answer in the dupe, or this [related one](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/17435/17787), alleged scores above 135 start to loose their meaning, which is not as far-reaching as many seem think to begin with. I scored an IQ of 257. Really. Am I a genius? Well, I might be, actually, But. No. The test was just bogus.

Comment: genius generally means above 145 or 150 IQ. they now call it "most exceptional" for PC reasons.

Comment: Well, Arsene Wenger and Frank Lampard had both retired from playing football by the time that article was written, so you can cross them off straight away.

Comment: Hi, i thought that a genius IQ is above 145, so i edited the title to exceptionally high.I know this article and other related articles probably aren't true, and its highly likely that they never took an IQ test, i just want to find out if there is a proof of their IQs. Sorry for bad typos (English is not my mother tongue).

Comment: Yeah, the IQ-cutoff for "_genius_" is subjective.  Some folks define it as 140+ (which is about 1 person in 261), while others go up to 160+ (which is about 1 person in 31,574), and there're plenty of other scales.  Not really a proper definition in general, though, much like there's no absolute cutoff for being "_tall_".

Comment: @LangLangC An IQ of 257 literally translates into getting the best score on an IQ test administered to ~1.6*10^25 people, or ~10^14 times the total number of humans ever born.  No actual IQ test should ever report such a score.

Comment: @Nat Right. But I swear 2 things: 1. my test reported exactly that (it just is not a scientific tool) 2. The numbers in question are equally bogus as well, for a number of reasons, and even if they were 'true', they are still meaningless, *absolutely meaningless*

Comment: @Nat - I don't think those numbers are correct.  Almost all of the tests have their highest categories in the 130+ or 140+ range.  The two most common standards, the Weschler and the Stanford-Binet have it at around 130.  A few others at around 140. For the Stanford-Binet scale and the KAB-II Assessment Battery, the highest possible score, not the threshold for the highest classification level, is 160. Maybe that's where you got that number from.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Without getting too tangential here, if you check out the table "_Terman's Stanford–Binet original (1916) classification_" in ["_IQ classification_"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IQ_classification#Historical_IQ_classification_tables), Wikipedia, it'll show that an early attempt to categorize genius put IQ's of 140+ as "_"Near" genius or genius_".  Later IQ scales haven't generally bothered, as the connection between IQ and genius isn't quite that simple.  But, generally, that's where the 140+ comes from, and why other definitions are stricter.

Comment: To anyone who has ever followed football, even just a bit, is quite obvious that Mario Balotelli's IQ is not higher than the one of a potato.

Comment: @Nat - I know, that's exactly what I was saying. When I say "I don't think those numbers are correct," I'm disputing the notion that any of the scales puts their highest category, or the concept of genius, as *starting* at 160+.